# Overhead Memory Off heap area

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

went through the documentation and understand that overhead memory is off heap , not part of JVM/garbage collection.

1. Memory overhead can set by (executor.memory.overhead) ie. (384MB, .07 * spark.executor.memory)? or
2. Usually when we do spark sizing , for ex: if size of a worker node is 64 GB, it is recommended to leave ~1GB for OS activities, and consider remaining 63GB for executor and overhead.

**Question** -  which of the above executor.memory.overhead (1st above) or 1GB (2nd above), is referred to as off-heap memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off-heap memory is different than overhead memory. It is counted toward the YARN container memory but is different than overhead memory. Below image depicts the different memory regions.

[image]

Comment: got it,thanks. what is the difference between off-heap and overhead memory? when to use one over other?

Comment: Basic difference is who uses that area. Overhead is used by respective resource managed (K8s or YARN), offheap is used by Spark. Both are outside JVM. Off heap is used by Spark for it own purpose like caching. Off heap helps sometimes in reducing GC issues.